# Build histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

Q: The gross incomes (in whole dollars only) of 100 employees, including part-time, of a
medium size company is given in the following table.
Construct the histogram using R to represent the following data.

[image]

Comment: SO isn't a homework writing service. What did you try so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide data in format below for future questions. But see the below code which gets you what you are looking for. You can also add `+coord_flip()` if you want something more aesthetically appealing.

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

tag_data <- c("[1-4,999]","[5,000-9,999]", "[5,000-14,999]", "[15,000-19,999]", "[20,000-24,999]", "[25,000-34,999]","[35,000-49,999]",
              "[50,000-99,999]","[100,000-149,999]")

tags <- factor(tag_data, levels=tag_data)

Frequency <- c(2,7,12,16,18,24,11,8,2)

income_level_data <- tibble(tags, Frequency = Frequency)

ggplot(income_level_data, aes(tag_data,Frequency)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(x='Income Level education', y = 'Frequency')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sorting it out. Indeed, I have been struggle to make it. The above histogram is perfect. Again, thank you!